# Accessibility service flagRequestTouchExplorationMode

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm implementing an Accessibility service and I need to intercept touch events on the views but when I add `flagRequestTouchExplorationMode` to the service configuration the phone stop responding and I need to build a version without that flag to regain control.

My service configuration xml is the following:

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeTouchInteractionStart"
    android:packageNames="xxx.yyyy.zzzz"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestTouchExplorationMode"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    />
```

What am i missing? Can somebody give me some hint?

Answer (score 1):

Touch exploration mode enables the low-level changes to input events that are generally used to place accessibility focus and detect specific gestures. It is not used to intercept touch events.

The best way to intercept touch events is to add a touchable accessibility overlay and capture the touch events dispatched to it.

Comment: Can you point to an example on how to do that?

Comment: Hi @TheOni did you manage to achieve this? I have a somewhat similar requirement.