# How to enable touch exploration mode on AccessibilityService

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, android-service, talkback

I'm trying to make a simple screen reader like talkback. But I got stuck at the step of activating touch exploration mode.

When enabling the service with the `flagRequestTouchExplorationMode` flag, the device freezes (as if it had disabled touch) at the following screen:

[device frozen after activating service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUZnc.png)

I suspect I have to manually handle navigation, but I have no idea how to do it.

**Service:**

```kotlin
class ScreenReaderService : AccessibilityService() {

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {

    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {

    }
}
```

**Service Config:**

```xml
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken|feedbackAudible|feedbackGeneric|feedbackHaptic"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRequestTouchExplorationMode|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="100" />
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```xml
...
<service
    android:name=".ScreenReaderService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
</service>
...
```

I'm basing myself on the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service).

I expected it to behave more or less like talkback.

**EDIT 1:**

I found the talkback project, I'm going to study it.

Comment: Related: [Accessibility service flagRequestTouchExplorationMode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53998876/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang already found this issue, and it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, but then I understood the device is not frozen it does not handle normal touch gestures, as i set android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"` this makes the service only listen for [accessibility_gestures](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151827?hl=en) if you perform accessibility gestures in the mobile it will give respond accordingly. Hope it helps